# Is it possible to have UISearchBarDelegate extension in separate file?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

```
extension HomeViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {


    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        //code
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
         //code     
    }
}
```

This was working fine when it was at the bottom of my HomeViewController.
 I wonder if I can separate this extension in separate file?

Comment: Haven’t you even tried it? And the answer is yes.

Comment: Ofc I did, but I got this error :
>Use of undeclared type 'UISearchBarDelegate'

Comment: @faris97 check to see if you've imported UIKit at the top of your new file

Comment: Including the error in your question would be a good idea in future.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include UIKit.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension HomeViewController {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)        {
      //code
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
     //code
    } 
}
```

Also, you need to inherit UISearchBarDelegate in ViewController, not in extension.

Comment: That isn’t true.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes it is possible.**

Hope you know about [extention](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) in swift.

`Extensions` is useful feature that helps in adding more functionality to an existing `Class`, `Structure`, `Enumeration` or a `Protocol` type. This includes adding functionalities for types where you don’t have the original source code.

**Code:**

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {

    var searchBar = UISearchBar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.searchBar.delegate = self   
    }
}
```

create another file named `HomeVC+SearchBarDelegate`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension HomeVC: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        //code
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
         //code
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this like below.

```
viewDidLoad(){
  let searchBar = UISearchBar()
  searchBar.delegate = DelegateFile()
}
```

> create a file.

```
class DelegateFile: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate{
    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        //
    }
}
```

Then implement your delegate methods in the seperate file.